# TikZ plot function: strange shift of coordinates when plotting custom functions

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I am observing a strange behaviour, namely, an unwanted horizontal shift of coordinates when plotting a function defined by `pgfmathdeclarefunction`.

Clearly, I am doing something wrong in the definition of the function, but what?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{line}{1}{
        \pgfmathparse{#1}
    }

    \makeatletter
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{Line}{1}{
        \begingroup
            \pgf@x=#1pt\relax
            \pgfmathreturn\pgf@x
        \endgroup
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin,color=gray](-0.1,-1.1) grid (18.1,3.1);
    
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
        \draw[thick,domain=0:1] plot (\x,\x);
        \draw[red,thick,domain=0:1] plot (\x,{line(\x)});
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
        \draw[blue,thick,domain=0:1] plot (\x,{Line(\x)});
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

The first definition (`line`) is merely a wrapper, in the second definition (`Line`) I followed exactly the syntax of the pgf tutorial.

The circles are just to demonstrate that somehow really the coordinate system was shifted.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{line}{1}{%%%%%%%%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%%%%%%%
}
    
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Line}{1}{%%%%%
    \begingroup
    \pgf@x=#1pt\relax
    \pgfmathreturn\pgf@x
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Don't know why TikZ doesn't ignore the spaces. However, there is only a problem for `pdflatex`/`lualatex`. But not for `xelatex`

Comment: Thanks, I was literally trying with putting % at the end of every line except the first one...